# MySQL PHP If Keyword Phrase From Table Does Not Exist In Sentence Table Show Results

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I have two tables: Sentences, Negatives.

I would like to select column Sentences.sentence that does not contain any record in Negatives.negphrase.

There are 200k records in Sentences and 50k records in Negatives.

```
Sentences.sentence Sample Data
=============================

 - university lab on campus
 - laboratory designs
 - lab coats
 - math lab
 - methane production
 - meth lab

Negatives.negphrase Sample Data
======================================

 - coats
 - math lab
 - meth

Desired Result Set
==================

 - university lab on campus
 - laboratory designs
 - methane production
```

I tried using the result of a different question of mine but the database timed out:

```
SELECT Sentences.sentence
FROM Sentences, Negatives
GROUP BY Sentences.sentence
HAVING (((Max(InStr(" " & sentence & " "," " & negphrase & " ")))=0));
```

**MY ANSWER**

So I'll give the correct answer to Richard b/c his solution does work for smaller record sets, but not large ones. Here is the PHP code I used to put all negative keywords in an array, then loop through that array with an UPDATE clause to mark a new column 'negmatch' in the Sentences table. I'll use that in another WHERE clause to select Sentences.sentence WHERE negmatch <> 1.

I only have to run this code once for all negphrases, then when I add additional keywords I use the same code but without a loop to search the sentences again (code not shown below). The code takes 6.5 minutes to loop through 2800 UPDATE clauses so the initial load is pretty long, but once it is done it doesn't have to be done again.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "myuser", "myuserpassword", "database");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT negphrase FROM negatives")) {  
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
    printf("Negative keywords have %d rows.\n", $row_cnt); //print count of rows

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ //loop through all results by row
        foreach( $row  AS $value ) {
        $negative[] = $value;
    }
}


    /* free result set */
    $result->close();

    $data = array_values($negative); // get only values
    $data = array_filter($data);
    $datacount = 1;
    foreach($data as $val) { //loop through array to build MySQL WHERE clause


            $updatequery = "UPDATE Sentences SET negmatch=1 WHERE sentence REGEXP '[[:<:]]" . trim($val) . "[[:>:]]'";
            echo $updatequery  . "<br />";

            mysqli_query($mysqli,$updatequery) or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
            echo $datacount . " " . trim($val) ."<br />";
            $datacount++;

        }

}
$mysqli->close();


    unset($result, $row, $mysqli,$value,$negative,$data,$val,$updatequery,$datacount,$row_cnt);
```

?>

Comment: So it looks like this is next to impossible in MySQL with large record sets, which I find ridiculous. 

My next approach is to put all Negatives.negphrase in an array, then loop through that array and execute another query to create an array of all Sentences.sentenceID if they match that negphrase. 

After the loop I would update a column in Sentences called negmatch and set it equal to 1 for each of those matches.

Any idea how to code this in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use negative left join, this will return only rows from Senteces table that doesn't match Negatives table based on rule

```
select * from Sentences s 
left join Negatives n 
on (concat(" ",s.sentence," ") like concat("% ",n.negphrase," %"))
where n.negphrase is null
```

tested on data bellow

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Negatives` (
  `negphrase` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `Negatives` (`negphrase`) VALUES
('coats'),
('math lab'),
('meth');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Sentences` (
  `sentence` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `Sentences` (`sentence`) VALUES
('university lab on campus'),
('laboratory designs'),
('lab coats'),
('math lab'),
('methane production'),
('meth lab'),
('testing sentence');
```

Comment: Thanks Richard. It totally works for small record sets but times out due to the number of records in my example (200k sentences, 50k keywords). 

Is there a way to speed this up, possibly by creating a new table that only holds the non-matching items? Then every time I added a new word to the negative list that table would be recreated?

Comment: You can use create table tempSentences as select * from Sentences. That would clone the table. Then, if you know some procedural extension of MySQL like https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html, you can write a for-cycle, that would go through the phrases in Negatives and delete all matching rows from tempSentences. The complexity will be still O(n*m) where n is number of Sentences and m is number of phrases.

If you want to optimize further, you can use fulltext indexes, or you can try something like Aho-Corasick implementation, but it would exceed the capability of MySQL itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.sentence FROM Sentences as t1
inner join Negatives as t2 on t1.sentence != t2.negphrase
```

make sure both column are index properly

Comment: Hi Payer, Thanks for the response. Unfortunately this just returns a result set of the first row of Sentences.sentence x 50k rows, then goes to the second row of Sentences.sentence and returns another 50k rows, etc.

Comment: It also requires a complete match of the record from Sentence to Negatives. I am looking to search within Sentence for Negatives and if there is a hit do not display that rows.